# Is there an implementation of tmpfs for Mac OS X?

Tags: mac

That is: a file system designed specifically for ramdisks? I know I could use any old file system but I want something specialized for performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/121989/can-i-put-tmp-and-var-log-in-a-ramdisk-on-os-x

Comment: Not a duplicate: I am looking for an optimized file system - that question just uses HFS+

Comment: It's unclear what you define as "an optimized file system".

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: *no, there's no Tmpfs for Mac OS X*. Tinkering with RAM-disks in Mac OS X is just naively mimicking what you get with [Linux Tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt) if you consider Linux' version as archetype — simply due to Tmpfs doesn't cut specified amount of RAM from system memory, allowing to <s>swap</s>page out its least-recently-used pages to swap.

Long answer is the same. ;)

Comment: I didn’t find any existing solution, but maybe we can [write one with FUSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003351/in-memory-fuse-filesystem)?

Comment: > Tmpfs doesn't cut specified amount of RAM from system memory

You can specify the size in `mount`

Comment: @interoception Linux' tmpfs' `size` parameter is the *maximum* size. What they meant is that it doesn't cut out a fixed amount but grows with usage.

Answer (score 5):

Once you have a ram disk device, you can put any fs on it you like.  HFS+ is going to be at least within an order of magnitude as good as any other fs.  Since you're on a Mac, it's the most natural FS to put on your ram disk.

But as stated in the other (duplicate) question's answer: unix is pretty darn good at caching files with memory it's not using for other things.  Taking space away from your OS and dedicating it to a ramdisk is usually not a good plan.

If you want to lower your i/o wait times and you have a very specific need, perhaps add an SSD to your system and use that.

Without knowing the details of your performance needs, it's very hard to answer your question with specifics.

Comment: Not necessarily a performance question, it could be a privacy  question. What's in a temporary fs will disappear after restart. Update: OOPS, I see the OP said it was for performance. My bad; I came here as a result of a search, and I'm doing it for privacy.

Answer (score 5):

There are couple of FUSE implementations, which should work on Mac:

- https://github.com/bbengfort/memfs
- https://github.com/thegreyd/FuseFilesystem

It seems you can also use `hdiutil`:

- https://github.com/coruus/osx-tmpfs
- https://gist.github.com/koshigoe/822455